# How do i request extra user data such as email,profile image from oauth/openID providers e,g facebook using Webmatrix beta 2 refresh oaythwebsecurity?

Tags: webmatrix

I just cant seem to get around the possibility of requesting and retrieving extradata such as profile image and email in facebook and gmail using oauthwebsecurity introduced in webmatrix beta 2.On default, gmail and yahoo returns email except facebook.None of them returns user's image.pls, how do i get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you are using Visual Studio 2012 then there's reference architecture built in to handle Facebook OAuth when building your website. Its broadly suggested to add the Facebook C# SDK via Nuget to enable calls to FacebookClient.

Its critical to understand that the first time you call Facebook Oauth for feedback it only gives back the following variables:

- id (can be email or mobile phone)
- name (user's Full name)
- link (link to their profile page on facebook)
- gender (male or female.. so little choice here)
- the access token

Once you have the access token you can use it to call the other variables. To see what you can get access to with the Facebook Client check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/   for a full listing of the various variables. (Noob alert: I still haven't figured out how to call all of them but the important bits are easy.)

There's an excellent tutorial by Scott MitzFacken on using OAuth providers in MVC websites and he takes you through each step except the most important one: getting the Extradata out using the access token and then getting it into your database. Follow his tutorial until you get to the point where this code is added to the ExternalLoginCallback method:

```
 if (result.ExtraData.Keys.Contains("accesstoken"))
{
    Session["facebooktoken"] = result.ExtraData["accesstoken"];
}
```

Ok so you've got your access token in the correct method. Now to get the data from Facebook and into your app. I amended the ExternalLoginConfirmation method just after the check to see if a user already exists:

```
 // Check if user already exists
 if (user == null) {

     var client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(Session["facebooktoken"].ToString());
     dynamic response = client.Get("me", new {
         fields = "first_name, last_name, email"
     });
     model.FirstName = response["first_name"];
     model.LastName = response["last_name"];
     model.EmailAddy = response["email"];


     // Insert name into the profile table
     db.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile {
         UserName = model.UserName, FullName = model.FullName, Gender = model.Gender, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, EmailAddy = model.EmailAddy
     });
     db.SaveChanges();
```

1. This assumes you have the Facebook C# SDK applied to your project.
2. The Facebook fields are requested in a single set of " " separated by a comma.
3. In my example the model.XXX refer to User Profile fields.
4. I then cast the User Profile fields to the response["XXX"] string.
5. When the User Profile record is saved the additional fields are also saved, thanks to the Facebook Oauth Client.

I'm not sure if you still need this answer... hopefully not. For noobs like myself who spent the entire day trying to get this right I hope this answer sheds some light on the subject

Cheers and Good luck!

Comment: I'll give you credit for your brilliant response but using facebook c# sdk will require another http request to facebook which will definitely affect performance. This issue has actually been resolved by the recent update on the OAUTH helper. there is now email on the extradata of facebook. I believe they added email as a permission parameter to the facebook graph api. Everybody ignored this question for a decade until i figured out multiple ways out of it. thanks!!!!

Comment: @IfeanyiChukwu: Thanks. I had an interesting situation yesterday where someone crashed the system because the email was not returned in extradata. This was most confusing until I dug a little deeper and found out that my test user had registered a long time ago with an email address that was no longer in existence. Facebook did not send the email addy because it had deactivated it - even though the profile itself was still active and the tester was allowed to login with the defunct email address. I introduced a if(response["email"]==null) statement to my methods to catch that error.

Comment: thats true! Exceptions from an api based callback from web servives such as facebook e.t.c is undeniably prone to occur. On extreme cases, wrap your code in a TRY/CATCH after validation to save yourself the pain. Also, create a file as an error log storage to monitor all this exceptions for later use. There seems to be a perfect fix on the latest OAUTHWEBSECURITY helper. Its really clean unlike the previous release version. cheers!!!